# kubernetes ingress control CrashLoopBackOff - no service with name kube-system/default-http-backend found

Tags: kubernetes

Based on this document https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/deployment/nginx/kubeadm
I am creating nginx controller. but my controller is not starting. its giving below error message.

```
2017-05-21T17:15:45.274300000Z I0521 17:15:45.259441       1 launch.go:101] &{NGINX 0.9.0-beta.5 git-83cb03b5 git@github.com:ixdy/kubernetes-ingress.git}
2017-05-21T17:15:45.274448000Z I0521 17:15:45.259460       1 launch.go:104] Watching for ingress class: nginx
2017-05-21T17:15:45.274563000Z I0521 17:15:45.259620       1 launch.go:257] Creating API server client for https://10.96.0.1:443
2017-05-21T17:15:45.274670000Z I0521 17:15:45.258931       1 nginx.go:180] starting NGINX process...
2017-05-21T17:15:45.310531000Z F0521 17:15:45.303209       1 launch.go:118] no service with name kube-system/default-http-backend found: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get services in the namespace "kube-system". (get services default-http-backend)
```

I see default backend service running.

```
$ kubectl  --kubeconfig=/c/software/k612_centos/admin.conf -n kube-system get po
NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-2198840601-zt8gt       1/1       Running            0          6m
nginx-ingress-controller-4108150732-q2rb2   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          6m
```

How to clear this error message?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which kubernetes version are you using?

If you are using kubenetes 1.6.x you need to define RBAC rules for the controller to access the default-http-backend service and other required components.

Please refer to this issue

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/575

The manifest file in the first comment worked fine for me.

Comment: I have the same problem on kubernetes 1.5.2 with ABAC authorization mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/nevetS/ingress/tree/master/examples/rbac/nginx) I found an example that is working find for me. Just for the record, I modified the RBAC to use the **default** service account of the nginx-ingress namespace because I already had a working gitlab installation that broke when enabling RBAC in the cluster.

Just in case the link becomes obsolete, I copy the RBAC settings below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
  namespace: nginx-ingress
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
        - events
    verbs:
        - create
        - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-role
  namespace: nginx-ingress
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-role-nisa-binding
  namespace: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
    namespace: nginx-ingress
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
    namespace: nginx-ingress
```